# Open up a Tab Item on a new thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, tabcontrol, threadpool

I want to add new `TabTtems` to my `TabControl`, but each `TabItem` must run on it's own `thread`.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I thought of using the `ThreadPool`:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandleNewTabItem),sender);

private void HandleNewTabItem(object sender)
{
    //Adding tabs...
}
```

Is this this correct way of running a `TabItem` on it's own `Thread`?

If not, what do you suggest?

**EDIT:**

The main reason for this is, i have allot of processing going on in my tabs and the user can add more and more tabs... So i need a way to handle all the processing and still keep my UI responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't say for sertain, will the ThreadPool use the different thread for each of your tab.

I don't think it suits for your task. Try to use a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class [with TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx):

```
Task<double>[] taskArray = new Task<double>[]
   {
       Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => DoComputation1()),

       // May be written more conveniently like this:
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoComputation2()),
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoComputation3())                
   };

double[] results = new double[taskArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
    results[i] = taskArray[i].Result;
```

**UPDATE**:

Why do you want to create a single thread for each tab? This operation is very memory consuming, and, if the number of threads is greater than number of cores in system, additional performance hit is being taken because of windows context switching.

This is why I suggest you to use tasks for your application - if numbers of tasks is greater than numbers of cores, your can wait for results by using of [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321405.aspx) method.

About your question from cooment:  Yes, your GUI will be responsive, as the tasks are executing with internally calls to the Thread pool object, and your are free to create new tasks by your TaskFactory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The main reason for this is, i have allot of processing going on in my tabs and the user can add more and more tabs... So i need a way to handle all the processing and still keep my UI responsive. That being said, will the `Task` class do the job for me?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post: [Multithreaded UI: HostVisual](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx)

It describes how to implement your own class that inherits from FrameworkElement and those contents are handled in its own thread.